# How I can skip one method in a class extending Abstract Class?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have one abstract class named `Animal` having around 100 methods including `swim`.

Many classes such as Dog,Cat ,Lion are extending that class.

Now there is one animal Giraffe which can't swim. But it is extending `Animal` abstract class.

I want that giraffe object does not have `swim` method.

```
Giraffe g = new Giraffe();
//g.swim();  // This swim should not come.
```

I cant change the Animal Class.
One solution is to create One more abstract class copying all the methods except swim.
But this is not a good approach.

How I can do this using Animal abstract class?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Why not to use interfaces like Swimable, Barkable and others and implement it.

Comment: The problem is that you have a bad design in `Animal` cause you are saying that an animal can swim.. a giraffe is an animal and cannot swim..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cause java guides by contract. If you are saying that an `Animal`  can swim then all animals can swim including a Giraffe, if it's not , then the giraffe it's not an animal.

The only thing you can do are without changing Animal

```
@Override
public void swim(){
 throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

The other thing you can do is making another class

```
public class Giraffe {

private final Animal a;

public Giraffe(Animal a){
  this.a=a;
}

public void method1(){
  a.method1();
}

public Something drink(){
  return a.drink();
}
.
.
.
// and not implementing swim 
}
```

Another is making a super-interface for Animal that don't have `swim()` method and make Animal implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot skip the definition of `swim()`. However, you can throw an exception for such cases.

```
void swim() throws CanNotSwimException{
}
```

Comment: @OP It might not be exactly the way you want it, but its definitely not wrong or off topic.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the most elegant solution would be to override the method, and throw a *OperationNotSupportedException*

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the situation, you could also just leave the method blank, if it is `void`.